# Data Table User defined functions

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with a column that lists the harmonized tariff codes for the goods that are being shipped. There are some input issues because sometimes a row may have repeated numbers "7601.00; 7601.00" and sometimes it might have different numbers, "7601.00; 8800.00". I have not decided what to do when I have differing entries, but the first thing I want to do is get rid of the duplicates. So I wrote a custom user defined function:

```
unique_hscodes <- function(hs_input){


  new <- strsplit(hs_input, split = ";")                   # Delimiter ;
  new <- lapply(new, str_replace_all, " ", "")

  if (length(unique(unlist(new))) == 1) {                  # Unique HS code
    return(unique(unlist(new)))
  }  
  else {

  new <- names(sort(table(unlist(new)),decreasing=TRUE)[1]) # Most frequent

  return(new) 

  } 

}
```

When I do, `DT[, hs_code := unique_hscodes(hscode)]` it returns me a data table with a column hs_code with the same number. But when I do `DT[, hs_code := unique_hscodes(hscode), by =1:nrow(DT)]`, it is done properly.

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Maybe `DT[, hs_code := sapply(hscode, unique_hscodes)]` works?

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns multiple items from a single item input after the string split. When you run it with by=1:nrow(DT) only a single row is examined at once. That problem doesn't arise when only a single row is presented.

```
 DT <- data.table(hscode=c("7601.00; 7601.00" , "7601.00; 8800.00"))
 DT
#-----
             hscode
1: 7601.00; 7601.00
2: 7601.00; 8800.00
#--
 DT[ ,  table( unlist( strsplit(hscode, split="; "))) ]

#7601.00 8800.00 
#      3       1 
 DT[ ,  table( unlist( strsplit(hscode, split="; "))) , by=1:nrow(DT)]
#---------
  nrow V1
1:    1  2
2:    2  1
3:    2  1
```

I tried @Jaap's code with the simple example but it only split the column in two:

```
> DT[, hs_code := sapply(hscode, unique_hscodes)]
> DT
             hscode hs_code
1: 7601.00; 7601.00 7601.00
2: 7601.00; 8800.00 7601.00
```

Comment: I thought the entire question was _why_, since the `by` operation was "working".

Comment: @Frank: I guess I thought that the other code was actually "getting rid of the duplicates", but it wasn't, I see now.